Lego 2017 batman joker bag 11

Batman and joker figures bag 11. Found bag by itself. Need info or instructions for build. Thanks.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
